# splitting table caption into multiple lines

Tags: pdf, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex, quarto

````
```{r echo=FALSE,warning=FALSE}
#| label: tbl-testTable
#| tbl-cap: Results of Accuracy and measures of confusion matrix Results for different number of insider trading transactions
#| tbl-subcap: ["Results of the benchmarking methods", "Results of different transactions \\newline and features in proposed method Random Forest"]

```
````

**Context:** I have two sub-tables with different captions in quarto (RMarkdown).

**Issue:** When I use `\\newline` in `tbl-cap`, the table rendered with multiple lines. When I use `\\newline` with the `tbl-subcap`, the line does not split, does not wrap with the table width and the caption overflows the width.

**Attempted Solution:** I tried `\\newline` to split the `tbl-subcap` into multiple line (see reference code above).

**Expected Solution:** I want the caption string to wrap with the width of the table and not to overflow the table width.

I tried `\\newline` to split the `tbl-subcap` into multiple line (see reference code above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your output format is pdf, you can latex package `subcaption` to tweak the subcaptions width using the command `\captionsetup[subtable]{width=<a-suitable-width>\textwidth}` instead of using the `\newline` command.

````
---
title: "Test"
format: pdf
include-in-header: 
  text: |
    \usepackage{caption}
    \captionsetup[table]{width=0.9\textwidth}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
    \captionsetup[subtable]{width=0.55\textwidth}
    \usepackage{float}
    \floatplacement{table}{H}
---


## Tables

```{r}
#| label: tbl-testTable
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| layout: "[[1], [-1], [1]]"
#| tbl-cap: Results of Accuracy and measures of confusion matrix Results for different number of insider trading transactions
#| tbl-subcap:
#|      - "Results of the benchmarking methods"
#|      - "Results of different transactions and features in proposed method Random Forest"

knitr::kable(head(CO2)) 
knitr::kable(head(CO2))
```
````